# CListCtrl does not render well elements' images

Tags: image, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CListCtrl and a Picture control and both are rendering the images wrongly. It is happenning for PNG images loaded through `CImage::Load`

[image]

The images are scaled down and have a vertical lines background that should not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is the need of a manifest, which I added to stdafx.h

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

[image]