# Application gives error only on 64 bit version

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, 64-bit

My application runs well if is the 32 bit version, but when I added the new 64 bit platform to the Configuration manager and tried to run it, I got the following message at startup:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [64bit manifest problem / side by side issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bddad9ee-942b-477a-a3a0-18e14a995d89/64bit-manifest-problem-side-by-side-issue?forum=vcgeneral#9e8d34a3-b812-49f9-bd8f-420399cde705) I concluded the problem was the manifest line

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

<s>So I add to branch it, conditioned by the platform:</s>

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

So, I add to turn it generic, independent of the platform:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Notice the difference in **processorArchitecture** value.

Now everything is working fine!

Comment: Well, don't do that, it isn't useful at all.  Use `processorArchitecture='*'`.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good catch! Where did you got the documentation for it?

Comment: @HansPassant: Your comment also made effect on http://stackoverflow.com/a/43098915/383779 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/43118615/383779